# Injecting <iframe> into HTML page without navigating to it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome extension to work with a certain website, and need to read the content of other pages at this website, but, at the background, without showing them in front of the user, but, due to the `same-origin` restrictions, I can't manage to read them at the extension's `background`, so, I'm trying to inject them at the `content-script`, as `iframe`, temporarily, until they render, before I read their html and delete the iframes eventually.

At the extension's `manifest` I'm setting `"all_frames": true`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://*.path/to/iframe/*?ext"
        ],
        "all_frames": true,
        "run_at": "document_idle",
        "js": [
            "iframe.js"
        ]
    },
   ...
]
```

And injecting the iframe as follows:

```
var $iframe = $('<iframe/>').attr('src', 'https://path/to/iframe?ext');
$('body').append($iframe);
```

**The problem is:** After injecting the iframe at the main page, the browser navigates the window.location to it.

#### How can I inject the iframe, access it, but without re-directing the main parent page to it?

---

I'm open to any other approach enables me from reading the html of these pages.

I tried `ajax` and jquery `.$get` before, but, the page renders dynamically, so, the initial html it spits isn't complete and what I'm looking for isn't ready yet when the ajax returns the html.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the navigation was happening, probably it was due to the website's code, but, I fixed the problem by changing the iframe url to be in a format that is accepted by the website, as they inject their own iframes by adding URL query to it, like this way:

```
<iframe src="/path/to/iframe?iframe=yes"></iframe>
```